# when using es6 function pattern so output is being undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scoping

```
let data2 = {
    address: 'New Delhi ',
    pin: '201206',
    details: () => {
        return this.address + " " + this.pin
    }
}
```

Here, when I call `data2.details()`, so output is undefined, but when using the es5 pattern,

```
let data2 = {
    address: 'New Delhi ',
    pin: '201206',
    details: function () {
        return this.address + " " + this.pin
    }
}
```

it’s working properly?

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between arrow functions and regular functions? You should look them up before find-and-replacing `function ()` to `() =>`.

Comment: i study about differences but can u please explain how will this code work

Comment: Arrow functions do not bind a `this` value, for instance. It is all explained in the question yours is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks solved this by - 

let data2 = {
    address: 'New Delhi ',
    pin: '201206',
    details () {
        return this.address + " " + this.pin
    }
}

so i didn't need a arrow function => if declaring method inside method !